# Is there a way to turn off df.to_sql logs?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using Pandas and SQLAlchemy to push data from CSVs into a MySQL database. When calling `df.to_sql()` thousands of lines of logs clutter the command line. Is there a way turn off/stop the logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think that is the standard behaviour of `to_sql()` but rather the parameter `echo=True` set in your sqlalchemy engine. Changing it back to `echo=False` or removing it since it is false as a default should stop it from printing out the logs.